# How do I get the result of SQL Query in C# Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using WPF, C#, Entity Framework database-first with a SQL Server database.

I could execute this query successfully in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(MEGHk) AS Meghksm, 
    SUM(MABL_K) AS Mablksm, 
    SUM(N_MOIN) AS N_MOINSM, 
    SUM(IMBAA) AS IMBAAsm 
FROM 
    INVO_LST 
WHERE
    (TAG = 2) AND (NUMBER = 4)
```

In C# code:

```
 var quer_Sumfactor5 = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<INVO_LST>("SELECT SUM(MEGHk) AS Meghksm, SUM(MABL_K) AS Mablksm, SUM(N_MOIN) AS N_MOINSM, SUM(IMBAA) AS IMBAAsm FROM INVO_LST WHERE(TAG = 2) AND (NUMBER = " + TextB_Number.Text + ")").ToList();
```

Which returns this error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How Select specify column in SQL query entity framwork c# wpf?

Comment: [I'm just going to leave this here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing aggregation on some of the columns in your query and have aliased the results of these aggregations. As a result the columns returned (`Meghksm`, `Mablksm` etc.) are not the same as those in the database table `INVO_LST` that your C# class `INVO_LST` is a representation of. So Entity Framework cannot map the results returned to the class that you have specified in your `dbms.Database.SqlQuery<INVO_LST>` call.

You need to create a class that EF can map to the results of the query:

```
public class INVO_LST_SUM
{
    public decimal Meghksm {get; set;}
    public decimal Mablksm {get; set;}
    public decimal N_MOINSM {get; set;}
    public decimal IMBAAsm {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can call:

```
var quer_Sumfactor5 = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<INVO_LST_SUM>("SELECT SUM(MEGHk) AS Meghksm, SUM(MABL_K) AS Mablksm, SUM(N_MOIN) AS N_MOINSM, SUM(IMBAA) AS IMBAAsm FROM INVO_LST WHERE(TAG = 2) AND (NUMBER = " + TextB_Number.Text + ")").ToList();
```

(although please carefully note @Liam 's comment re SQL injection...)

Answer (score -1):

first of all you should read the sql injection. You should not use the  " TextB_Number.Text " in your query , as it can result in less data security.
Secondly,`dbms.Database.SqlQuery<INVO_LST>` SqLQuery expects a class that can match the type and name of the columns that will come in query result.
So you should use following approach.

```
public class INVO_LST_SUM
{
   public decimal Meghksm {get; set;}
   public decimal Mablksm {get; set;}
   public decimal N_MOINSM {get; set;}
   public decimal IMBAAsm {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
var quer_Sumfactor5 = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<INVO_LST_SUM>("SELECT SUM(MEGHk) AS Meghksm, SUM(MABL_K) AS Mablksm, SUM(N_MOIN) AS N_MOINSM, SUM(IMBAA) AS IMBAAsm FROM INVO_LST WHERE(TAG = 2) AND (NUMBER = " + TextB_Number.Text + ")").ToList();
```

Use decimal instead of int,, As the aggregate function Sum can results in Decimal value also.